# List ports tunnelled on OpenSSH server

Tags: openssh, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

Is there any way to list the tunnels that SSH clients connected to my OpenSSH server have set up?

I can use e.g. `lsof -i` to show connections that are being actively tunnelled, but I'd like to be able to list tunnels that the clients have set up but may not currently be in use.

(It's just struck me that this may be an entirely client-side thing, i.e. the server only knows the client is set up to tunnel a port when something tries to connect through the tunnel, in which case the answer will be "you can't" - but I'll take that as an answer if so.)

(Background: I'm running a MineCraft server on a machine that won't be able to do much else while it's running. If I can monitor when users have tunnels set up, I can run up the MC server on demand.)

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that you actually aren't talking about tunnels.

Comment: I don't see how my use-case is so outlandish. Tunnelling ports to localhost isn't too unusual, and isn't really relevant to the question. All I want to know is whether the server providing the tunnel is aware the tunnel is there between the SSH connection being made and the tunnelled connection being made, and if so, how to get a list of these tunnels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well yes it is client sided.

Plus there isn't any configuration in the traditional sense. You create a tunnel by specifying the correct parameters when connecting to a server.

Sure you can store it in `.bashrc`, `.ssh/config`, or some other place for re-usability, but in general it is purely on-demand.

Comment: You say "specifying the correct parameters when connecting to a server". Do you mean when you make the original SSH connection, or when the e.g. MC client connects to (client) localhost and gets tunnelled to the server? If its the former, that means the server is aware of the potential tunnel even when it's not being tunneled through. If it's the latter then the server knows nothing about the potential tunnel until the tunneled client connects.

Comment: @Rawling Well, if you run `ssh -L 5000:mail_server.cz:110 ssh_account.cz` then it will create a tunnel going from your local port 5000 through the `ssh_account.cz` machine to the port 110 on `mail_server.cz`. If you run `ssh -R 80:localhost:800 ssh_account.cz` it will create a tunnel going from the port 80 on `ssh_account.cz` to your local port 800.

Comment: @Rawling And these tunnels, won't exist until created.

Comment: So the server knows literally nothing about the tunnels until the e.g. mail client/web client actually uses them? In which case... bad news for my use case, but at least it's an answer.

Comment: @Rawling Uh? What do you mean by: "mail client/web client uses them"? If you are routing mail/web traffic through a tunnel, that tunnel has to be created before you do that (manually).

Comment: Ah... hm. Take your first example, you call `ssh -L 5000:mail_server.cz:110 ssh_account.cz` on your SSH client. That connects to `mail_server.cz`, but `mail_server.cz` doesn't know about the `-L 5000:mail_server.cz:100` bit yet. Then your mail client connects to `localhost:5000`, and the SSH client then requests a tunnel from `mail_server.cz`. This is the first `mail_server.cz` knows that the client was set up to create a tunnel in the first place... is that right?

Comment: @Rawling Nope, that doesn't connect to `mail_server.cz` at all. It connects to `ssh_account.cz` where it creates the tunnel and when a connection is received on the localhosts port 5000 it is routed encrypted through the `ssh_account.cz` machine (which doesn't see this connection) to `mail_server.cz` which sees a connection from `ssh_account.cz` and doesn't see the tunnel going back to localhost.

Comment: Ah damn, I misread. (In my case `mail_server.cz` and `ssh_account.cz` are the same machine.) Would it be correct to say that `ssh_account.cz` does not know about the `-L 5000:mail_server.cz:100` part until the mail client connects? Or does the `ssh_account.cz` set up the tunnel as soon as the initial SSH connection is set up?

Comment: @Rawling What? That doesn't make sense. Why would you create a tunnel going to the same machine?

Comment: In this case, because I only want one port open on my firewall, I don't trust the Minecraft server to be listening to all and sundry on the internet... And I want to be able to use "authorised Minecraft user logged in via SSH" as a cheap check for turning the MC server on and off.

Comment: @Rawling I still don't get what you are tunneling. If you don't want open ports, simply close all ports except for the ones required by Minecraft. There is no tunneling involved. Plus if you would tunnel local ports, then you are the one creating the tunnel, so the question doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I just don't want Minecraft listening on an open port; I trust the MC server less than I trust OpenSSH. In theory the MC server could be running on a separate machine, on the same LAN as the OpenSSH server.  Everyone I want to be able to play MC will have a 'nix account and the permissions on the OpenSSH server to create a tunnel from a local port to the MC port on the MC server. They set the tunnel up in their SSH client, connect SSH, and then run up the MC client which uses the tunnel to connect. I want to know if the SSH server is aware of the tunnel even while MC itself is not connected.

Comment: It is on-demand.  Port forwarding is not fixed at the time the user connections.  Many SSH clients, including putty & openssh can modify the forwarded ports while the user is connected.   With openssh, the user just has to hit a special escape key, then they can add or remove forwarded ports.  See the `ESCAPE CHARACTERS` section of the man page for details.

Comment: With that confirmation, I'll mark this as correct. Thanks for the patience in clarifying :)